# T-bird taillight control unit digital logic help

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I am currently working on designing a t-bird tail light control unit. The requirements for the system are presented on the table below: [image]

I have a full circuit made which I'll provide in the screenshot below:[image]

So far, my circuit works for all of the scenarios EXCEPT for when the left/right lights are supposed to flash while the other set of lights is supposed to be on. What happens is when I OR the B input with the output of the AND gates from the state machine, the lights that are supposed to flash do not since B is feeding the OR gate a constant 1, however the other set of lights that are supposed to constantly stay on do stay on as they should. I have been struggling trying to solve my problem here but have not been able to so I came on here for ideas. Any help will be appreciated.
(The circuit works for all of the scenarios except the one mentioned above.)

Comment: What is a "t-bird tail light"?

Comment: @Hearth Tail lights for a [Ford Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Thunderbird) car. This is a surprisingly standard lab/homework problem in digital logic and state machines. The Ford Mustang revived the "sequential taillights" in 2010.

Comment: The original Ford Mustang and Mercury Cougar has sequential turn signal lights.  The timing was done with a DC motor turning an shaft with machined three cams, each operating a microswitch to control one of the three lights.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is Flash OR instead of L/R XOR Flash.
i.e. L/R Flash out= (L/R XOR M ) AND Flash in

Solid On = L/R AND not M

That is why it fails.